# Stopping to take a Photograph

Tags: tips

Ok I used to live near this old junkyard and I always drove by it on my way home.  Almost everyday I would say the same thing to myself.

> bring your camera tomorrow and take a picture!

Well wouldn't you know, the city came by and cleaned up the yard and in doing so it lost all it's appeal.  Since that day I swore that I would never procrastinate if I saw a location that needed shooting.

Until the other day when I drove by this tree during the Sunset, and I said to myself.

> bring your camera tomorrow and take a picture!

Well I still haven't done that so I am wondering how many people actually stop, get out of their vehicles, and take a photograph spontaneously?  How many do what I have done but actually return?  Same day? Next Day?

I keep kicking myself over the Junkyard and I have only seen a similar sunset behind the tree twice now, so I might just have to keep my camera with me from now on.

Comment: I walk to work for this reason...

Comment: This could be interesting discussion, but I don't think there's really an answerable question here. (Other than "me too!")

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate question as worded. There's not answer, its a survey.

Comment: Yeah, should probably be CW, or at least reworded to be "How do you overcome..."

Comment: It would be better posed as a discussion on the [site's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14)

Answer (score 4):

I try to keep my camera in the car when I can (when temps inside a parked car allow), but I still find myself failing to stop because:

- I don't want to cause a traffic hazard
- There's no good place to park
- I don't want someone getting upset that I'm taking a photo of their property
- I'm late
- It's too cold outside
- It's too hot outside
- It'll probably be there tomorrow (whatever it is)

Thanks for the reminder that the camera's not going to operate itself!

Answer (score 3):

I do this in "vacation mode" on road trips, but that's only because:

- I already have my gear with me
- It's a place that I'll "never go to again" (even if I know I will)
- I'm already in "stop and smell the roses" mode instead of day-to-day life mode.

And this assumes I have time to do so / not on a tight schedule.

Beyond that though, I'm very guilty of this. Sometimes I consider picking up a point-and-shoot specifically for this purpose.